Is it possible for a contract to completely prevent incoming ETH transfers?
Can a contract be designed in such a way that it will always have a balance of zero ETH?
Maybe this can be achieved by skipping the payable modifier in all functions, and not implementing the fallback receive function?

No. It is impossible to guarantee that an Ethereum contract will always have a zero ETH balance.
From the Solidity docs:

Neither contracts nor “external accounts” are currently able to prevent someone from sending them Ether. Contracts can react on and reject a regular transfer, but there are ways to move Ether without creating a message call. One way is to simply “mine to” the contract address and the second way is using selfdestruct(x).

